# Hide div when product has been added to cart

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a bit of JQuery to hide a div when a product has been added to cart. I'm using AJAX add to cart and have the following:

```
$( document.body ).on("added_to_cart", function() {
    alert('added to cart');
    $(".purchase-processing").css("display","none");
});
```

However it doesn't work (the alert or the hiding). Am I tying it in to the wrong event or something?

Comment: write the css property before the alert , if its not working try with "hide".  please add your html code here so, that we can check?

Comment: @sukumar2267 It doesn't work even if I have just the alert, or just the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document.body ).on("added_to_cart", function() {
    $(".purchase-processing").css("display","none");                        
    alert('added to cart');
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will sole your issue:

```
$(document).on("click", ".added_to_cart", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('added to cart');
    $(".purchase-processing").hide();
});
```

N.B: If "added_to_cart" is an ID then add # sign before it instead of dot(.)

Add to cart usually works with jQuery AJAX by no refreshing the page. So if in your case this is happened what I'm saying then you can do that like this code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".added_to_cart", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your/php/function/link/where/product/added/processing',
        type: 'POST',
        data: demoData( of course in JSON format)
    }).done(function(res) {
        var resp = $.parseJSON(res);
        if (resp.status) {
            alert('Item successfully added to cart.');
            $(".purchase-processing").fadeOut();
        } else {
            alert('Error! when adding item to cart.');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: perhaps I wasn't clear enough: I want to hide the div at the same time as the "product has been added to your order" notice appears. The div .purchase-processing is shown when you click the add to cart button, then is meant to just be displayed until product has been successfully added to cart- ie. added to cart notice pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout function for apply css.
It’ll work.

Comment: it doesn't- the issue isn't with applying the CSS, it's that the code doesn't fire at all- not even the alert.